# wait for a jbutton click to continue with program execution java

Tags: java, swing

how can I know in main method that one button is click to continue with the execution because the code doesn't work inside the actionperfomed button.

For example this is my main method

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
jwindows jw = new jwindows ();

//stop until a button inside the jwindows is clicked

// codeExecuteAfterButtonClick 

}
```

Comment: maybe you could show us the code in the event handler?

Comment: You should use a `JDialog` of some kind, see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: A solution is a thread.sleep() but its not best solution I guess

Comment: Use another class as class call your class. And implement your class runnable interface and write suspend and resume method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wait` and `notify` methods is Object exist to handle this sort of situation

```
final JButton button = new JButton('click to continue');
button.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    synchronized (button) {
      button.notify();
    }
  }
});
JFrame jf = new JFrame("Window");
jf.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(...);
jf.pack();
jf.setVisible();
synchronized(button) {
  try {
    button.wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.println("Interrupted");
  }
}
System.out.println("After button clicked");
```